# Is it possible to access types from assemblies specified by CSharpCompilation.ExternalReferences?

Tags: c#, reflection, roslyn, sourcegenerators

I'm trying to write a source generator to remove boilerplate code in a project. The purpose of the project is to generate new unit tests for the "exercise" code from the existing unit tests of the "solution" code. I'll give a short example below:

```
// The "solution" code
public void Name_InitializesAsNull() {
  Solutions.Person person = new Solutions.Person();
  Assert.IsNull(person.Name);
}

// The "exercise" code
public void Name_InitializesAsNull() {
  Exercises.Person person = new Exercise.Person();
  Assert.IsNull(person.Name);
}
```

In order to generate this additional method, I want to validate that the class Exercises.Person has a readable field or a property Name. I have previously done this through reflection, and would like to continue to do so.

So my question is: Is it possible to access type information, like MemberInfo, during source generation of types in the assemblies specified by CSharpCompilation.ExternalReferences?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but keep in mind source generators are additive, they cannot remove/modify existing code. The way you word the question sounds like your looking to change one form into the other and omit the former.

Comment: I am aware, but thanks for the heads up, and I will be modifying my question. If you are curious about my solution to that potential problem, it will be to only mark the "exercise" code with the appropriate attributes, like TestClass. This will make MSTest only detect the "exercise" code.